# How to implement one to many relation, while allowing efficient searches either way?

Tags: c++

I think this question is best explained in the context it came upon me. If you disagree, jump to the next horizontal rule.

I'm developing a virtual board game as a way to improve my C++. Right now I'm facing a problem.

There are several tiles in the game ("spaces" in which you can be in), each one of them can have several monsters in it. Because of the features that I aim for, it is necessary to know which monsters are in each tile and also in which tile is each monster.

This makes me wonder: should I introduce an array in the tile class that will hold pointers to all monster in that tile, or is it better to introduce a pointer in each monster that points to the tile they're currently in? Or maybe both at the same time?

---

Or, more abstractly:

Objects of type 'A'can relate to zero or more objects of type 'B'. Objects of type 'B' can relate to one and only one object of type 'A'. Given that efficient searches must be done either way (find out which 'B' objects a specific 'A' object is related to and, conversely, which 'A' object is a specific 'B' object related to), what is the best way to implement this behaviour?

If this is in any way unclear, ask me so I can provide further explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `A` and `B` refers to the name of the objects -- be it a pointer, smart pointer, guid into a table, or whatever.

You create a map from `A` to `B`s (zero or more `B`s), and an entry within each `B` specifying an `A`.  The map from `A` to `B`s could be a simple `vector<B>` within instances of things named by `A`s, for example, or a space partitioning tree of the space that the things named by `A`s are in, or an unordered multimap, or whatever.

Determine where lifetime management should go.  Determine if you want weak pointer like behaviour, or dumb pointer like behaviour, in your names.  The second requires manual cleanup at lifetime end: the other defers that work to point of use.

Comment: This complements mine in terms of how to go about the implementation. Excellent showmanship of library standards usages.

Comment: So basically, there's no way around a map AND a pointer in each B? I though that maybe there was a neat data structure that would avoid the redundancy.

Comment: @jlang sure, a boost multi index, but that isn't worth it usually.

Comment: @JLagana You don't have to. You can put the position(e.g., (x,y) coords) of the tile inside the monster. But that's just another way of dependency.

Comment: Another alternative is boost bimap